# Flash / As3 - Is There a Way to Do Virtual/Overridable Constants?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

In actionscript 3 you can't make override variables, but why? You can override the getter / setter for it so what is the difference? The problem I'm having is that I want to define constants in the base class and then have the subclasses decide what value each one should be.

In my case suppose I have a class, 'Character', and a subclass 'BillyBob' that extends from it.

If I want the Character class to be able to say, "All subclasses of me have to have the constants 'ON_SCREEN_X' and 'EXPLOSION_MULTIPLIER', but they can give them whatever values they want." This would be nice if they were constants in BillyBob. However, it seems that const's defined in the base class can't be set at the class level, since they are const can't be set in any methods. :(

Comment: Constants by definition remain constant (not dynamic) throughout the running of your program. They are efficient because the machine has to remember them only once and then never double check or re-calculate their values. Can **public static** variables not work for you? But I like Marty's suggestion below...

Answer (score 3):

> In actionscript 3 you can't make override variables, but why?

Sure you can - change its value in the subclass?

> You can override the getter / setter for it so what is the difference?

The difference is that getters and setters are functions that contain implementation you might want to alter in a subclass, whereas a flat value can simply be changed.

> All subclasses of me have to have the constants `ON_SCREEN_X` and `EXPLOSION_MULTIPLIER`, but they can give them whatever values they want.

The way to do this is using getters. I am not sure why you want constants in place of this but I personally would do something along the lines of:

```
public class Character {
    public function get explosionMultiplier():Number { return 1; }
}

public class BillyBob extends Character {
    public override function get explosionMultiplier():Number { return 1.2; }
}
```

Note that because you've only implemented getters here, these properties do share similarities to constants in that they are read-only.